# date input field should be optional in php

Tags: php, mysql

Hi guys i have a from where user is going to select a course from drop down and second input user will select expired date that should be optional.so when user didn't give date it is showing error as `Your Due date should be in future.`

I don't know why it is showing like that if i didn't give any date in input field also.

here is my code:

```
if (isset($_POST['assigncourse'])) {

    $courseid = $_POST['courseid'];
    //$duedate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['duedate']));
    $duedate = strtotime($_POST['duedate']);
    $now = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
    if ($now < $duedate) 
    {
        $courseid = required_param('courseid', PARAM_TEXT);
        $groupid = required_param('groupid', PARAM_TEXT);

        $insert_record = new stdClass();
        $insert_record->courseid = $courseid;
        $insert_record->groupid = $_SESSION['groupid'];
        $insert_record->duedate = $duedate;
        $insert_record->createdby= $id;
        $insert_record->createdon = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $sql1 = "SELECT *  
                    FROM mdl_ppc_assigncourses_group 
                    WHERE groupid='".$_SESSION['groupid']."' 
                    AND courseid='$courseid'";
        $courses = $DB->get_records_sql($sql1);
        if (count($courses) > 1) {
            $errorMessage = "The course already taken!";
        } else {
        $DB->insert_record('ppc_assigncourses_group', $insert_record);
        }
    } else {
        $errorMessage = "Your Due date should be in future.";
    }
}
```

Here is my form:

```
<!-- /.card-header -->

<form class="form-horizontal" id="sign-in" style="margin-left: -2px; padding: 15px 15px 0px 15px" method="post" role="form"  data-parsley-validate="" novalidate=""> 
        <input type="hidden" name="groupid" class="col-md-12 form-control" id="inputEmail3"  required="" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['groupid']; ?>" >
        <!-- select -->
         <input type="hidden" name="depid" class="col-md-12 form-control" id="inputEmail3"  required="" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['depid']; ?>" >
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Choose Course</label>
            <select name="courseid" id="courseid" class="form-control" required>     
                <?php
                $sql = "select id,fullname from {course} where id!='1' ";
                $courses = $DB->get_records_sql($sql);
                ?>

                <option value="">Choose Course</option>
                <?php
                if (sizeof($courses)): foreach ($courses as $row):
                        $coursename = $row->fullname;
                        ?> 
                        <option value="<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><?php echo $row->fullname; ?></option> 
                        <?php
                    endforeach;
                endif;
                ?>        
            </select> 
        </div>
         <div class="form-group label-floating">
            <label class="control-label">Due Date</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="duedate" > 
        </div>

      <div class="form-group">
          <button  type="submit" name="assigncourse"  id="submit"  class="btn btn-info form-control">Assign</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Can anyone help me what mistake i have done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is if duedate is not set. $now cannot be smaller than duedate.

This line:

```
if ($now < $duedate)
```

you will have to change. Make it so it looks if $duedate is set in first place.

```
    if (isset($_POST['assigncourse'])) {

    $courseid = $_POST['courseid'];
    //$duedate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['duedate']));


    if(isset($_POST['duedate']) && ($_POST['duedate'] != "")) {
          $duedate = strtotime($_POST['duedate']);
        }
        else {
          $duedate = false;
        }
        $now = strtotime(date('Y-m-d'));
        if ((!$duedate) || ($now < $duedate)) 
        {
            $courseid = required_param('courseid', PARAM_TEXT);
        $groupid = required_param('groupid', PARAM_TEXT);

        $insert_record = new stdClass();
        $insert_record->courseid = $courseid;
        $insert_record->groupid = $_SESSION['groupid'];
        if(is_numeric($duedate)) {
          $insert_record->duedate = $duedate;
        }
        else {
           $insert_record->duedate = time();
        }
        $insert_record->createdby= $id;
        $insert_record->createdon = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
        $sql1 = "SELECT *  
                    FROM mdl_ppc_assigncourses_group 
                    WHERE groupid='".$_SESSION['groupid']."' 
                    AND courseid='$courseid'";
        $courses = $DB->get_records_sql($sql1);
        if (count($courses) > 1) {
            $errorMessage = "The course already taken!";
        } else {
        $DB->insert_record('ppc_assigncourses_group', $insert_record);
        }
    } else {
        $errorMessage = "Your Due date should be in future.";
    }
}
```

ViewPage:

```
<td><?php if($duedate > 0) { echo date('Y-M-d',$duedate); } ?></td>
```

Comment: i have added like that so when  i didn't add date and when i just added course and try to submit it is not taking it

Comment: what i have to change

Comment: getting error in this line  if(is_numeric($duedate) { Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in

Comment: missing a ), sorry

Comment: This should do it

Comment: its adding but its not displaying the courses in my view i am just checking one min

Comment: Is the data in the DB?

Comment: yes it is but my query is like this thats why its not showing     $retval = "SELECT mc.fullname,mpag.courseid,mc.id as cid,mpag.asgid,mpag.groupid,mpag.duedate FROM `mdl_ppc_assigncourses_group` mpag JOIN mdl_course mc ON mpag.courseid=mc.id where groupid='" . $_SESSION['groupid'] . "' and mpag.status='1' and mpag.duedate>=CURDATE()";

Comment: i am trying to get the results depending on curdate can u pls tell me how can i correct my query because after duedate passes i will move that courses to inactive courses list thats why i have written like that

Comment: The problem lies again in the duedate... the statement needs a duedate. What should it default to? now? I updated the answer above to default the duedate to now.

Comment: You could also just do this:
"SELECT mc.fullname,mpag.courseid,mc.id as cid,mpag.asgid,mpag.groupid,mpag.duedate FROM mdl_ppc_assigncourses_group mpag JOIN mdl_course mc ON mpag.courseid=mc.id where groupid='" . $_SESSION['groupid'] . "' and mpag.status='1' and (mpag.duedate>=CURDATE() OR mpag.duedate is null)";

Comment: sure it is working but it is showing date in view page as like this 1970-Jan-01

Comment: how can we display as empty if there is null value in db?

Comment: Send me code for view page. Is the Database field (duedate) an integer?

Comment: <td><?php echo date('Y-M-d',$duedate); ?></td> that is my td which i am displaying for duedate..yes it is bigint(10)

Comment: see the solution in answer and let me know
You could now make a - else { echo "No Duedate provided"; } - 
if you want ;-)

Comment: Not a problem, have fun!

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the `$duedate` has a value.  You would do that like this.

```
if(isset($duedate) && $duedate){

if(strtotime($now) < strtotime($duedate)){

echo 'Do something';

}else{

echo 'Do something else.';

}

}else{

echo 'You need to enter a due date.';

}
```

Your code would look like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['assigncourse'])) {

    $courseid = $_POST['courseid'];
    //$duedate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['duedate']));
    //$duedate = strtotime($_POST['duedate']);
    $now = date('Y-m-d');

    if(isset($_POST['duedate']) && $_POST['duedate']){


      if(strtotime($now) < strtotime($_POST['duedate'])) 
      {
          $courseid = required_param('courseid', PARAM_TEXT);
          $groupid = required_param('groupid', PARAM_TEXT);

          $insert_record = new stdClass();
          $insert_record->courseid = $courseid;
          $insert_record->groupid = $_SESSION['groupid'];
          $insert_record->duedate = $duedate;
          $insert_record->createdby= $id;
          $insert_record->createdon = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
          $sql1 = "SELECT *  
                      FROM mdl_ppc_assigncourses_group 
                      WHERE groupid='".$_SESSION['groupid']."' 
                      AND courseid='$courseid'";
          $courses = $DB->get_records_sql($sql1);
          if (count($courses) > 1) {
              $errorMessage = "The course already taken!";
          }else{
          $DB->insert_record('ppc_assigncourses_group', $insert_record);
          }
      }else{
          $errorMessage = "Your Due date should be in future.";
      }
    }

}
```

Comment: yeah checking that